# FFMPEG cannot encode video with high speed change

Tags: ffmpeg

Hi I am trying to speed up and trim clips with FFMPEG version 4.2.2. Is there a limit to how fast you can speed up a clip? If I try to speed up a clip over a certain then the output file cannot be opened.

I have tried two methods without any luck: 1. using the setPTS filter and 2. inputing the file at a faster frame rate.

1.

```
ffmpeg -i GH012088.MP4 -y -ss 18 -t 0.48 -an -filter:v "setpts=0.096*PTS" -r 25 output.MP4
```

2.

```
ffmpeg -r 312.1875 -i GH012088.MP4 -y -ss 18 -t 0.48 -r 25 -an output.MP4
```

I am trying to create a clip from the input that starts at 1 second in the original clip, plays at 10.4166 x speed and lasts for 0.48 seconds

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You are trying to speed up 0.48s by 10x, so 0.05 s. Assuming your input is 25 fps, that's 1.2 frames i.e. 1 or 2 frames. Many players like older versions of VLC try to cache more frames that before starting playback.

Comment: I thought that since I have the '-t' durations argument is after the '-i' input argument that it defines the duration of the final encoded video not of the input video?

Comment: I am trying to create a clip from the input that starts at 1 second in the original clip, plays at 10.4166 x speed and lasts for 0.48 seconds. Are my use of the -ss an -t arguments incorrect for this?

Comment: Sorry, I misconstrued the commands. What's the duration of the original file?

Comment: It is 40.473767 seconds long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -ss 1 -i GH012088.MP4 -y -t 0.48 -an -filter:v "setpts=0.096*PTS" -r 25 output.MP4
```

The seek has to be on the input side, before frames are retimed. The `-t` has to be on output side, after frames are retimed.

Answer (score 0):

Does the movie have sound?
If yes, than we have to sync speed up audio and video by combine filter:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -f avi video1.avi
```

Comment: It does have sound however I do not mind about it. I am just trying to create a clip from the input that starts at 1 second in the original clip, plays at 10.4166 x speed and lasts for 0.48 seconds